# datetimepicker widget weird placement

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

**Actual problem**

I've included the code snippet for better troubleshooting but itself got a problem, however please refer to the image below, you notice that the datetimepicker widget is behind the table. How to make it in front of everything?

[image]

**Code snippet**

The datetimepicker is acting weird.

Refer to the code snippet, I'm having an error which it does not provide the proper error message. I've included all proper cdn.

Additionally, the datetimepicker widget can appear but it was placed at the bottom of the result box.

```js
  $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format : "DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm"
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/><link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<label for="datefrom">Date From</label>
<input id="datefrom" name="datefrom" type="text" class="datetimepicker"/>
                
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Receipt No/Ref No</th>
        <th>Payment Method</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>01-10-2017</td>
      <td>DOB Balance</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td>Cash</td>
      <td>$1000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01-10-2017</td>
      <td>DOB Balance</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td>Cash</td>
      <td>$1000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01-10-2017</td>
      <td>DOB Balance</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td>Cheque</td>
      <td>$1000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01-10-2017</td>
      <td>DOB Balance</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td>TT</td>
      <td>$1000</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: try to add higher z-index to the calendar container

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this. If that helps accept the answer.

```js
  $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format : "DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm"
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/><link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div style="position: relative">
    <label for="datefrom">Date From</label>
    <input id="datefrom" name="datefrom" type="text" class="datetimepicker"/>
</div>

                
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Receipt No/Ref No</th>
        <th>Payment Method</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>01-10-2017</td>
      <td>DOB Balance</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td>Cash</td>
      <td>$1000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01-10-2017</td>
      <td>DOB Balance</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td>Cash</td>
      <td>$1000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01-10-2017</td>
      <td>DOB Balance</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td>Cheque</td>
      <td>$1000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01-10-2017</td>
      <td>DOB Balance</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td>TT</td>
      <td>$1000</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used bootstrap Date picker. So, you need to follow their rules. Please check their documentation fist http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Bootstrap datetimepicker component should be placed within a relative positioned container.